# Prevent multiple login without interfering with DB

Tags: javascript, java, spring

my question is about how to prevent multiple login (ie : same username and password ), initially I start by setting indicator in DB. But it didn't work when user close the tab or browser. Then tried with session , but it didn't work too when user tries to login on different browser, since each browser has different session. I need a perfect solution.

Comment: Store user id in session and a boolean true if logged in, check this session variable for the user when trying to log in.

Comment: I would  solve such cases, by inserting in DB session ID as active assigned to a specific user. By relogin from different browser, system will flag other sessions as expired...

Comment: If user close the application by tab close, in such case how to handle if session id is stored in DB